# Make an optimal white space between an image and the top menu

Tags: padding

I have a website where i have a menu with position fixed and then an image.

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYjYo.jpg)

But i had to make some top padding in the image so you can see all the image and the top menu doesn't stay on top of the image beacouse of the position fixed. This is how it looks without the menu

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTQCB.jpg)

But I made that space with pixels, so its not optimal and not responsive.
If anyone can help me. It can be done with JS if necessari, but i still don't know JS.
Thx

I just tried to put padding-top: ...px, with rem or vh, nothing else